# Manifold with a quasi-positive curvature

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, curvature

As far as I know, in a simply connected compact manifold, still there exists no well-known obstruction for a manifold with a **quasi-positive curvature** to be a manifold with **positive curvature**.

But Hopf's conjecture is unsolved, i.e., the conjecture: $S^2\times S^2$ has a positive curvature.

So I think that the quasi-positive curvature-condition can be weakened by conditions : **non-negative curvature** and non-flatness.

Here my concrete question is : Is there a simply connected compact simple 
Lie group which does not have a metric with a positive curvature and has a metric with a non-negative curvature ?

[Definitions]

Here we say that a Riemannian manifold $M$ has positive (resp. non-negative) curvature if all sectional curvatures are positive (resp. non-negative) at all points of $M$ And a manifold with quasi-positive curvature is a manifold with a non-negative curvature and a point at which all tangent 2-planes have positive curvature.

Comment: Could you please clarify the question? (I suppose that the last sentence of your post is in doubt and you would like to know if it's a true statement?)

Comment: Okay I will clarify my question.

Comment: what you call "to be positively curved" should be termed "to admit a positively curved Riemannian metric"

Comment: That's right. And I eddited.

Comment: What did you edit? your edited post still contains "be a positively curved manifold" in an ambiguous sense.

Comment: What you are asking about is a well-known open problem. See the survey by Ziller: http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wziller/papers/SurveyMexico.pdf for most recent summary of obstructions and examples. Also the biinvariant metric on any simply-connected compact Lie group has nonnegative curvature (this is an easy exercise in Do Carmo's "Riemannian geometry'').

Comment: @Igor: Although the only compact Lie groups that have a *positively* curved bi-invariant metric are $SU(2)$ and $SO(3)$, I am unaware of results about non-existence of (possibly non-invariant) positively curved metrics on compact Lie groups. Do you know any such result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For high rank Lie group, this is in fact the generalized Hopf conjecture which is still open.